# From small to big owl-carousel center mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

My goal is to make a carousel that looks like this:

[image]

From small to big.

In case you don't know what you're looking at, there are 5 images/items but only the center one is displayed in its full size. The images next to the center one are smaller, and the outer ones smaller still.

But actually the owl carousel classes (`medium`, `big`) for realizing this is already deprecated .

I wondering  is this possible to make something like that in my owl-carousel ?

Here's the link to what I did in [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/4mbwk3j1/2/)

Please do change's in my fiddle .

**Downvoter's please comment first**

```
/**
 * Plugin for linking multiple owl instances
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @author David Deutsch
 * @license The MIT License (MIT)
 */
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    /**
     * Creates the Linked plugin.
     * @class The Linked Plugin
     * @param {Owl} carousel - The Owl Carousel
     */
    var Linked = function(carousel) {
        /**
         * Reference to the core.
         * @protected
         * @type {Owl}
         */
        this._core = carousel;

        /**
         * All event handlers.
         * @protected
         * @type {Object}
         */
        this._handlers = {
            'dragged.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function(e) {
                if (e.namespace && this._core.settings.linked) {
                    this.update(e);
                }
            }, this),
            'linked.to.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function(e, index, speed, standard, propagate) {
                if (e.namespace && this._core.settings.linked) {
                    this.toSlide(index, speed, propagate);
                }
            }, this)
        };

        // register event handlers
        this._core.$element.on(this._handlers);

        // set default options
        this._core.options = $.extend({}, Linked.Defaults, this._core.options);
    };

    /**
     * Default options.
     * @public
     */
    Linked.Defaults = {
        linked: false
    };

    /**
     * Updated linked instances
     */
    Linked.prototype.update = function(e) {
        this.toSlide( e.relatedTarget.relative(e.item.index) );
    };

    /**
     * Carry out the to.owl.carousel proxy function
     * @param {int} index
     * @param {int} speed
     * @param {bool} propagate
     */
    Linked.prototype.toSlide = function(index, speed, propagate) {
        var id = this._core.$element.attr('id'),
            linked = typeof(this._core.settings.linked) === 'string' ? this._core.settings.linked.split(',') : this._core.settings.linked;

        if ( typeof propagate == 'undefined' ) {
            propagate = true;
        }

        index = index || 0;

        if ( propagate ) {
            $.each(linked, function(i, el){
                $(el).trigger('linked.to.owl.carousel', [index, 300, true, false]);
            });
        } else {
            this._core.$element.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [index, 300, true]);

            if ( this._core.settings.current ) {
                this._core._plugins.current.switchTo(index);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Destroys the plugin.
     * @protected
     */
    Linked.prototype.destroy = function() {
        var handler, property;

        for (handler in this._handlers) {
            this.$element.off(handler, this._handlers[handler]);
        }
        for (property in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
            typeof this[property] != 'function' && (this[property] = null);
        }
    };

    $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins.linked = Linked;

})(window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window, document);


$(".carousel_1").owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    items: 1,
    margin:1,
    linked: ".carousel_2"
});
var sync2 = $(".carousel_2");
$(sync2).owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    loop:true,
    items: 4,
    margin:10,
    center:true,
    linked: sync2.prev()
}).on('initialized.owl.carousel linked.to.owl.carousel', function() {
    sync2.find('.owl-item.current').removeClass('current');
    var current = sync2.find('.owl-item.active.center').length ? sync2.find('.owl-item.active.center') : sync2.find('.owl-item.active').eq(0);
    current.addClass('current');
});
```

What I tried !!!

I tried to add this part of code when first carousel(**carousel_1**) config is ended

In there I try to choose first and last item and gave them classname and in this classname I'll change them `width` or `height` .

But this solution only take's a first and last item I need all item's from left and right to center

ALso in this solution didn't worked write like that

`if(index == 1)` Instead of number one any **index** could be .This is adding two classes to one element .

```
checkClasses();
$(".carousel_2").on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    checkClasses();
});

function checkClasses(){
    var total = $('.carousel_2 .owl-stage .owl-item.active').length;

    $('.carousel_2 .owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('firstActiveItem lastActiveItem');

    $('.carousel_2 .owl-stage .owl-item.active').each(function(index){

        if (index === 0) {
            // this is the first one
        $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
        }
        if (index === total - 1 && total>1) {
            // this is the last one
            $(this).addClass('firstActiveItem');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I've been working with owl-carousal for more than 5 months and I have never seen something like this in owl-carousal. But I found a demo what actually you are looking for. http://wowslider.com/js-image-slider-premium-page-demo.html Go to the carousal tag and check. This may help you

Comment: @Ramesh ty for help but owl carousel have this method's also link which you gave I don't see anything in there look like in img that I paste

Comment: In the link can you some few blue buttons under the slider. In that find out the option **carousal** and click it.There you find what you want.It's not actually what you want but with few configurations you can achieve it. And thank you for letting me know that owl-carousal can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece of code in your CSS will work for it,

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    max-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.carousel_2 .active.center + .active,.carousel_2 .active:first-child,
.carousel_2 :not(.active) + .active{
   height:150px;
}
.carousel_2 .active.center{
   height:200px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img{height:100%}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4mbwk3j1/28/)**

*Update* for the `7` and/or `n` number items, css will not work but you can use jQuery code like,

```
$('.h-150px').removeClass('h-150px');
$('.h-200px').removeClass('h-200px');
// add class to just next/prev active element
current.next('.active').addClass('h-150px').end().prev('.active').addClass('h-150px');
// add class to just second next/prev active element
current.next('.active').next('.active').addClass('h-110px').end()
      .end().prev('.active').prev('.active').addClass('h-110px');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/4mbwk3j1/69/)**